# Signing a TideSDK App

Tags: code-signing, tidesdk

We've recently ported a legacy Adobe AIR app over to TideSDK and the only thing that I can't find a nice solution to is signing the app. Assuming that they are, how are other TideSDK developers signing their apps for both Windows and OS X? Google seems pretty silent on the issue.

Any insight or even just a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone playing along at home, I have a custom Python build script that wraps `tidebuilder.py` and does some extra stuff like creating a customized disk image, etc. To this wrapper, I added the following code to sign the app created by `tidebuilder.py`:

```
# Use the security exeucutable to ensure that we have the certificate installed
security import tidesdk/package/cert.p12 -k $HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P <cert password> -T /usr/bin/codesign

# Sign the .app "file"
codesign -s "<cert common name>" /path/to/MyApp.app

# Verify the signed app
codesign -v /path/to/MyApp.app
```

I'll update this answer when I find an analogous solution for Windows.